# PHP Header = Location in a different folder in directory

Tags: php

If I had a page inside of an includes folder but wanted a `header("location: dashboard.php");` to redirect out of the folder into the main directory, how would I do this?

I want to come out of two folders to the main directory.

Comment: Show us what you have tried

Comment: So, what? `Location: /dashboard.php`?

Comment: `../` 1 step down. `../../` 2 steps down. `../../../` 3 steps down. *Shall I go on?*

Comment: *"to redirect out of the folder into the main directory"* - The *real* question is: *What is your **main** directory*??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this (relative addressing):

```
header("location: ../dashboard.php"); // for one folder
header("location: ../../dashboard.php"); // for two folders
```

Comment: *"I want to come out of **two** folders to the main directory."* - that's only one. Then again, who knows what their structure looks like.

Answer (score 1):

Get the server name using superglobal $_SERVER and add rest of the path.

```
$path = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/the path';
header("location: " . $path ."/dashboard.php");
```

because you enclose it in double quotes below is correct as well

```
header("location: $path/dashboard.php");
```